# How to get Home Page title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to show home page title in breadcrumb. I have tried the `get_the_title()` function, but it requires page id as parameter. I believe it will break when I change the front page to other page.
Is there a function that is more change prone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is how I solved my problem

```
$home_title = get_the_title( get_option('page_on_front') );
```

that way, when I change home page with diferent page, the code won't break. It also works on multisite.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this..

```
<?php echo bloginfo('title'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo bloginfo('title'); ?>
```

This will echo you title of your website given in settings.

Comment: my home page title and site title is different

Comment: Then you can pass home page ID through this `get_the_title( $id )` in wordpress every page has a unique ID.

Comment: the problem is it will break when I change the front page to other page

Comment: pass a constant ID for the page like `get_the_title( 50 )` not like `get_the_title( get_the_ID() )`